# rake db:test:prepare or :clone dont create test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake

As topic says, if I do a `rake db:test:prepare` or `rake db:test:clone` no test.sqlite3 gets created. Also did a `db:migrate` before

Terminal dont give any output.

Thats my database.yml

```
sqlite: &sqlite
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%= Rails.env %>.sqlite3

mysql: &mysql
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password:
  database: myapp_<%= Rails.env %>

postgresql: &postgresql
  adapter: postgresql
  username: postgres
  password:
  database: myapp_<%= Rails.env %>
  min_messages: ERROR

defaults: &defaults
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  <<: *<%= ENV['DB'] || "sqlite" %>

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

Any Ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Did you get a debug output while running it with `-d`

Comment: rake aborted!
ambiguous option: -d

Comment: Is `ENV['DB']` actually set as something by default, thereby short circuiting your logic?

Comment: see my answer, forgot to set this up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah me is stupid...

had to give the rails.env, due to my database.yml with the command

`RAILS_ENV=test rake db:test:prepare`